# Trouble multiplying 2D arrays of different dimensions in Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I've got the following code, I'm trying to get it to multiply array a by array b and produce array c. I've browsed several questions on here and for some reason I can't get the array to produce the correct results, I believe because it's not multiplying the right indices by one another. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am still trying to grasp how array multiplication works. Here is the code:

```
    class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    int[][]a = 
    {
      {1,2,3,4},
      {5,6,7,8},
      {9,10,11,12},
      //print array a
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length-1; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++)
      {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }


    int[][]b = 
    {
      {-1,-2,-3},
      {-4,-5,-6},
      {-7,-8,-9},
      {-10,-11,-12},
    };
    System.out.println();
    //print array b
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < b.length-1; j++)
      {
        System.out.print(b[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

    int[][]c = new int[a.length][b[0].length];

    if(b.length == a[0].length)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++)
        {

          for (int k = 0; k < a[0].length; k++)
          {
            c[i][j] = a[i][k]*b[k][j];

          }
         }  
       } 
    }


    else
    { 
      System.out.println("Dimension requirements not satisfied for accurate calculation");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < c.length; j++)
      {
        System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `c[i][j] = a[i][k]*b[k][j];` to `c[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j];`

Comment: doing that gives me and array of 
`-70 -80 -90 
-158 -184 -210 
-246 -288 -330`

that's much higher than any of the values in the two arrays could produce isn't it? am I looping something too many times?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Jeffrey Chen is correct because in the matrix multiplication each row of the first matrix multiply by each column of second matrix

In your case row 1 of matrix a is 1, 2, 3, 4
Column 1 of matrix b is -1, -4, -7, -10

So the answer is (1*-1)+(2*-4)+(3*-7)+(4*-10)
= -1-8-21-40 = -70

Then the first row of matrix a multiply by second column of matrix b

(1*-2)+(2*-5)+(3*-8)+(4*-11)
= -2-10-24-44 = -80

And so on

So the following is correct

```
c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
```

Comment: thank you, to you and jeffrey, I'm starting to understand arrays a little better in java